# How to pass my own smart pointer to function?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

There is smart pointer class:

```
template <typename T>
class UniquePtr {
public:
    UniquePtr(T* obj)
        : obj(obj)
    {
    }
    UniquePtr(const UniquePtr& ptr) = delete;
    UniquePtr(UniquePtr&& ptr)
    {
        std::cout << "!! use of move !!" << std::endl;
        obj = std::move(ptr.obj);
        ptr.obj = nullptr;
    }

    UniquePtr& operator=(const UniquePtr& ptr) = delete;
    UniquePtr& operator=(const UniquePtr&& ptr) = delete;

    ~UniquePtr()
    {
        delete obj;
    }

private:
    T* obj;
};
```

class for test:

```
class Test {
public:
    Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test is created" << std::endl;
    }
    Test(const Test& obj) = delete;
    Test(const Test&& obj) = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test& obj) = delete;
    Test& operator=(const Test&& obj) = delete;
    virtual ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test is destructed" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

and function:

```
void function(UniquePtr<Test>&& ptr)
{
    std::vector<UniquePtr<Test>> v;
    v.push_back(std::move(ptr));
}
```

If I pass Test class, everything is OK:

```
UniquePtr<Test> ptr(new Test);
function(std::move(ptr));
```

But if I pass derived from Test class, code isn't compiled:

```
class TestChild : public Test {
public:
    TestChild()
    {
        std::cout << "Test child is created" << std::endl;
    }
    TestChild(const TestChild& obj) = delete;
    TestChild(const TestChild&& obj) = delete;
    TestChild& operator=(const TestChild& obj) = delete;
    TestChild& operator=(const TestChild&& obj) = delete;
    virtual ~TestChild()
    {
        std::cout << "Test child is destructed" << std::endl;
    }
};
UniquePtr<TestChild> ptr(new TestChild);
function(std::move(ptr));
```

> ```
> error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘UniquePtr&&’ from
> expression of type ‘std::remove_reference&>::type {aka UniquePtr}’
> function(std::move(ptr)); ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
> ```

How can I make `UniquePtr<TestChild>` convertible to `UniquePtr<Test>&&`
With `std::unique_ptr` this code works.

Comment: (don't have time for a full answer) [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) provides a constructor that makes the conversion possible : `template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept;` You need to replicate that functionality

Comment: This is odd: `obj = std::move(ptr.obj);`, `obj` being a pointer.

Comment: @YSC, yes, you're right, it's not necessary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much like how [`std::unique_ptr` handles it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr), you need to provide a templated constructor for your class that takes a `UniquePtr` of a different type (allowing SFINAE to deal with inheritance checking), which will then be used to initialize your `UniquePtr`'s state.

```
template<typename U>
UniquePtr(UniquePtr<U> && other) {
    obj = other.obj;//Won't compile if U is not a subclass of T.
    other.obj = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It works. But, I make constructor like this: 
`
template <typename U> UniquePtr(UniquePtr<U>&& ptr) 
{ 
obj = ptr.get(); 
ptr.reset(); 
}
`
Because `Unique_Ptr<U>` has other type and obj becomes inaccessible

Comment: however, I found better solution, I added `template <typename U> friend class UniquePtr;`. It gives me access to private members